# Rewrite path without extension to include extension

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to rewrite `http://localhost/az` to `http://localhost/az.vcf` (which exists as a file I want to be able to download.

I tried:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    root /www/data;
    rewrite ^(/.*) $1.vcf last;
}

types {
    text/x-vcard vcf;
}
```

I can download the file but it has no `.vcf` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite mechanism works only with internal `$uri` variable. It does not affect URL in the browser address bar so it can't affect the downloaded file name. If you don't want to do a HTTP 301 redirect

```
rewrite ^(/.*(?<!\.vcf))$ $1.vcf permanent;
```

or HTTP 302 redrect

```
rewrite ^(/.*(?<!\.vcf))$ $1.vcf redirect;
```

you can try to add the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to your response:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    root /www/data;
    rewrite ^(?<path>.*/)(?<name>[^/]*) $path$name.vcf last;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$name.vcf"';
}
```